# How to change textures in OpenGL using Haskell

Tags: opengl, haskell

I'm stuck trying to get multiple textures working in OpenGL using Haskell. I've been following the NeHe tuts and some various other OpenGL resources online, but the combination of slightly different calls and my newbness has caused a roadblock.

To be specific I want to render two cubes, each with a different texture (same texture for all 6 faces for the time being). Rendering one cube, with a texture is fine. Rendering multiple cubes of the same texture works fine as well. But I've not been able to figure out how to change textures for the two cubes

If I'm not mistaken the call to change textures is:

```
textureBinding $ Texture2D $= Just *mytexture*
```

where *mytexture* is supposed to be some form of textureID (a TextureObject). **What the heck goes into the *mytexture* spot?** This should be really easy but I've spent the better part of 2 days trying to figure this out to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Main:

```
    -- imports --
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL
import Graphics.UI.GLUT
import Data.IORef
import Display
import Bindings
import Control.Monad
import Textures

-- main --
main = do
    (program, _) <- getArgsAndInitialize         -- convenience, return program name and non-GLUT commands
    initialDisplayMode $= [DoubleBuffered, WithDepthBuffer] -- inital display mode
    initialWindowSize $= Size 600 600
    createWindow "OpenGL Basics"
    reshapeCallback $= Just reshape
    angle <- newIORef (0.1::GLfloat) -- linked to angle of rotation (speed?)
    delta <- newIORef (0.1::GLfloat)
    position <- newIORef (0.0::GLfloat, 0.0) -- position, pass to display
    texture Texture2D $= Enabled
    tex <- getAndCreateTextures ["goldblock","pumpkintop"]
    keyboardMouseCallback $= Just (keyboardMouse delta position) --require keys, delta, and position
    idleCallback $= Just (idle angle delta) --ref idle angle and delta
    displayCallback $= (display angle position tex) --ref display angle and delta
    cullFace $= Just Front 
    mainLoop    -- runs forever until a hard exit is called
```

In *Main* I call getAndCreateTextures (borrowed from the net), which returns a list of texture objects.

Display (for rendering):

```
    -- display (main) --
display angle position tex = do
    clear [ColorBuffer, DepthBuffer]
    loadIdentity --modelview
    shadeModel $= Smooth
    (x,z) <- get position --get current position from init or keys
    translate $ Vector3 x 0 z -- move to the position before drawing stuff
--    DO STUFF HERE
--    texture $ Texture2D $= Just wtfgoeshere
    preservingMatrix $ do
        a <- get angle
        rotate a $ Vector3 (1::GLfloat) 0 0
--        rotate a $ Vector3 0 0 (1::GLfloat)
        rotate a $ Vector3 0 (1::GLfloat) 0
--        scale 0.7 0.7 (0.7::GLfloat)
--        color $ Color3 (0.5::GLfloat) (0.1::GLfloat) (0.1::GLfloat)
        cubeTexture (0.1::GLfloat)
    swapBuffers

--idle (main)
idle angle delta = do
    a <- get angle      -- get existing angle
    d <- get delta      -- get delta
    angle $= a + d      -- new angle is old angle plus plus delta
    postRedisplay Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAndCreateTextures` is almost certainly doing what you need. The function of that name I found on the web has type `IO [Maybe TextureObject]`, those are the `TextureObject` values you need. So you could do,

```
[gtex, ptex] <- getAndCreateTextures ["goldblock","pumpkintop"]
textureBinding Texture2D $= gtex
```

for example.

Comment: Ding ding ding! This allows me to load multiple textures and pass them to the rendering portion. Next thoughts, as the list of textures grows, in the current setup I would have to pass each texture to display before being able to call them. To simplify the passing of multiple textures, I would just call the getAndCreateTextures in a separate area and return a large list of textures as one variable, correct?

Comment: @llanoraw In general you will separate the loading of textures and their usage. You may be able to load all your textures at startup, or you may want to load a few at a time based on the currently visible scene. You may want to consider pairing up geometry with the necessary `TextureObject`(s) in a record, then render that record.

Answer (score -1):

You pass the texture object. `getAndCreateTextures` seemingly gives you a list of texture objects. You pass one of those to the binding, like

```
textureBinding $ Texture2D $= Just tex[0]
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking..although it fails to run. I get a type mismatch: Expected type TextureTarget, actual type IO()

Comment: `$` make it like you're putting all the right side into one argument to `textureBinding`.